# MySQL Prepared Statement Syntax Error in Variable

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a stored procedure that will execute a prepared `SELECT` statement based on input parameters.  The non-dynamic version of this procedure works fine- that is, it seems that the underlying `SELECT` query works.  When I call the dynamic procedure I am getting a syntax error on the `WHERE` clause.  I can't see what's wrong and am asking for another set of eyes.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS find_batter;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE find_batter
    ( #input age, position, and parent org 
    IN age_param SMALLINT (6),
    IN position_param VARCHAR (15),
    IN org_param VARCHAR (10)
    )
BEGIN

   DECLARE select_clause VARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE where_clause VARCHAR (500);
   DECLARE order_clause VARCHAR (200);


   SET select_clause = "SELECT concat(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) as player
     ...
       ";

     SET where_clause= "WHERE p.retired=0 AND b.year=2015 AND b.PA>50";

   IF age_param IS NOT NULL THEN
     SET where_clause = concat(where_clause, ‘ AND ‘, age_param, ‘>=p.age’);
   END IF;
   ...
```

I'm getting a syntax error telling me to check near `p.retired` in the `WHERE` clause.  The rest of the IF statements are going through as coded - the dynamic where statements are showing up in the error, so I'm thinking the problem is at the first `SET` statement. I just don't see it.

EDIT: The issue was no space before "WHERE".

Comment: After assembling the sql statement, just print it out, do not execute it. You will probably see what's wrong with it straight away (my guess is that there is no space before the where)

Comment: Yep! No space before where.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I'm seeing in the code is funky Windowz-style smart quotes in the code.

```
SET where_clause = concat(where_clause, ‘ AND ‘, age_param, ‘>=p.age’);
--                                      ^     ^             ^       ^
```

As a first step, I suggest replacing the funky quotes with plain vanilla ascii 39 (0x27) single quotes characters.

```
SET where_clause = concat(where_clause, ' AND ', age_param, '>=p.age');
--                                      ^     ^             ^       ^
```